# memoir, hyperref, \MakeTextLowercase and \cftchapterfont

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, memoir

Using the combination `\MakeTextLowercase` and `\cftchapterfont` in the `memoir` class with the `hyperref` package causes strange issues when attempting to make the table of contents’ chapter titles minuscule.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterfont}{\MakeTextLowercase}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{This Is a Chapter}
\end{document}
```

[image: garbled pdf output]

The first errors are like this, and then follows a load of missing/extra `{`/`}` and control sequences.

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\find@pdflink ...ode \protected@edef \Hy@testname
                                                  {#2}\ifx \Hy@testname \@em...
l.1 ...entsline {chapter}{Contents}{1}{section*.1}
```

I think some packages/fonts have an option to always use minuscule small caps, but I want to use `garamondx` and from my reading of the `garamondx` manual, I have yet to find a way. How can I make `hyperref` behave?

Comment: `\MakeTextLowercase` is not expandable and can't go to the ToC  generated with `hyperref`

Comment: Besides, `\MakeTextLowercase` is not a font changing declaration. The `\cftchapterfont` should be defined as a declaration such as `\scshape` or `\bfseries`, whereas `\MakeTextLowercase` is a command taking an argument.

Comment: Hyperref modifies \contentsline to produce a \hyperlink, and \cftchapterfont is applied AFTER \contentsline (inside \l@chapter).

Comment: What alteratives are there in that case? Is there a font declaration for rendering minuscule small caps, indiscriminately?

Comment: I took the inspiration from section 9.2 (p. 155) in the `memoir` manual, so assumed it was appropriate: `\renewcommand\cftchapterfont{\scshape\MakeTextLowercase}`

Comment: Chapter has a [short title] option for the toc.

Comment: Is there a way to make it do that automatically, without it giving errors about the use of `\@chapter` not matching the definition, or being unusable when you actually want another title in the ToC?

Comment: See page 158 in the manual, there is an entire named section about this issue.